# Is Google Analytics client ID kept when updating to a new app version?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, analytics, tagging

Google Analytics (GA) sets a `client ID` for the app, based on one specific instance or installation. Please also see:

> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid

Below scenarios are true:

1. User has multiple devices with the app installed = multiple client IDs = multiple users are measured in GA for this particular user.
2. User removes and re-installs the app = new client ID = multiple users are measured in GA for this particular user.

But what if someone updates the app to a new version. Does GA calculate this as a re-installation?

I think your app will be removed quickly (so it looks like on your smartphone, since the app dissapears for a moment) and the new version will be restored.

Also, if your client ID is kept somewhere, how does Google remember your client ID when doing an app update?

Comment: I can't find a proper reference for this, but I know from experience, that the client ID is kept during an app update. Also, if the app is removed and installed (instead of update), all other app settings and cache would be lost.

Comment: Thank you. Anyone with a reference?